# realsense2_camera_manager crashes

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

when launching the realsense D435 with

```
roslaunch realsense2_camera rs_rgbd.launch
```

it starts and everything is fine. I have tried that on my Desktop and a NUC that I am trying to setup.
As soon as I subscribe any /camera/aligned_depth_to_*/ * topic the nodelet crashes

[camera/realsense2_camera_manager-2] process has died [pid 16059, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/nodelet/nodelet manager __name:=realsense2_camera_manager __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/228fa30e-f642-11e9-bdc0-d43b04b8f565/camera-realsense2_camera_manager-2.log]

Any suggestions on how to fix? Since the nodelet runs fine on my Desktop even after subscribing I do not think its actually a realsense2_camera problem. All other topics work fine on both pcs.

Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336063/realsense2_camera_manager-crashes/) by [chris93](https://answers.ros.org/users/46863/chris93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2019-10-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually a fresh install did the trick. On the NUC the SDK1.0 and the realsense_camera has been installed before. Seems like the uninstall is not clean enough or something failed for me.
Nevertheless in my case the installation of sdk2.0 and realsense2_camera did not work even after I completely wiped ROS and everything else related to it. Only a fresh install of ubuntu worked.

Cheers

---

Originally posted by [chris93](https://answers.ros.org/users/46863/chris93/) with karma: 26 on 2019-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0